# Maximize and undecorate all apps in Xubuntu

Tags: window-manager, xubuntu

On my netbook I'm running Xubuntu as it works much faster than Unity 2D. I'd like to have all the apps maximized and undecorated, is there any way to do that without Compiz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go someway towards this with the package `maximus` available from synaptic/software center

#### [maximus](https://web.archive.org/web/20151231014808/http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=maximus) [image: Install maximus]

The image below shows maximising windows in Xubuntu using `maximus`.

[image]

To test, start maximus via

```
nohup maximus &
```

One issue I found with maximus under XFCE (xubuntu 11.04) - Windows will start maximised but not undecorated - you need to click the maximise button twice.

Use the Q&A below to add the command line above to your XFCE/Xubuntu startup applications.

---

Linked Question:

- [Modify xfce startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77066/modify-xfce-startup-applications)

Comment: ever figure a way around that xfce double click problem? @fossfreedom

Comment: I havent tried since this question since I dont really like the "global menu" type effect in xfce - I use it in standard menu mode.  But I presume given your question this still occurs with the latest version of xfce :(

Comment: well xubuntu 12.04 here. not sure what version of xfce im at.