# Modify xfce startup applications

Tags: startup, xfce

Normally I like it when a terminal window pops up immediately after startup, since I'm a heavy CLI user in linux.  However, my preference is to have the terminal maximized, particularly on my laptop, and the standard xfce4 startup execution leaves the terminal window to standard size.

I've tried the following:

- Checked the .desktop files in both /usr/share/applications & /.local/share/applications
- Checked `xinitrc` in /ect/xdg/ for terminal startup.  A change here resolved an issue with both xfce & gnome screensavers running simultaneously, but did nothing for the terminal issue.
- Checked Application Autostart in `xfce4-session-settings`, but there's no default terminal entry.  When I add one, two terminal windows pop up on startup.

According to several guides I've found, editing the `xinitrc` file is key to the startup.  However, I found no explicit terminal execution calls in that file.

What is needed to modify the default terminal startup settings?

**EDIT**

After further investigation, it turns out it was a setting in GNOME that set the process off.  I switch between GNOME, KDE and xfce for desktop environments, and the terminal popup was based on the GNOME startup settings.  When that was modified, the terminal now shows up full-sized with no problems.

Answer (score 19):

go to Configuration/Systemsettings/Session and Startup (i'm not sure about the exact names since my comp is in Spanish but you shouldn't have much trouble finding it) and add a new startup app with "name" - put here the name you want, it's not important

`command = xfce4-terminal --fullscreen`

and you're done. Also maybe check out Tilda and Guake for drop-down terminal emulators if you really are a fan of cli.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Turns out its a gnome-terminal instance that is running on startup, not xfce4-terminal.  When I tried your suggestion, a second terminal window opened up and `ps -A | grep term` showed both gnome-terminal and xfce4-terminal running simultaneously.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but can't mark this as an answer because it didn't resolve the problem.  Appreciate the help though!

Comment: English is : Settings / Settings Manager / Sessions and startup

Comment: xfce4-terminal also supports the `--drop-down` argument. Unlike guake it does not require it's own python instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a *.desktop file add it to autostart directory -

```
nano ~/.config/autostart/app.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=app
Exec=app 
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```