# Start a web browser application with no window borders

Tags: chromium

How can I start a web browser with no window borders and buttons?

I am thinking at something like this:

```
chromium-browser my-file.html --no-borders --no-tabs
```

In my mind this would open Chromium with no title bar, with no tabs and no buttons for close, minimize and so on.

I would need also an API for Javascript for closing, maximizing, resizing and dragging the window... For example if `myFile.html` contains a button when I click it, somewhere in js side will be called a function that will close the browser window.

Is there any tool?

Comment: Maybe you should look at [The QtWebKit Bridge](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html). It can give you full control over your window and expose any native functionality to your HTML-based app.

Comment: About your second question is better ask it in [so]

Comment: I use Bodhi Linux, and they provide a way to change the window border for ANY window. That's wonderful. There's something to dig in their code for the ones who are interested about window-borders management through a GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `--app`:

> --app=URL:              Runs URL in "app mode": with no browser toolbars.

So, `chromium-browser --app=/path/to/my-file.html` should be an option.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I'm using gnome3 so window has to be decorated, but I presume there is some way for unity/kde/etc.

Comment: Almost correct. But I don't need the title bar. How can I remove it?

Comment: @Johnツ read the last line.

Comment: Can you please add more information about that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/56927/169736

Comment: Discovered `devilspie` application that I think I will use. Thanks!